# Why the debugging order is different in IE and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, internet-explorer-11

I currently have the following code in my javascript file.

```
Line 100.
$(document).on('change', '#elementName', function ()
Line 500.
$(document).on('click', '#elementName', function ()
```

Initially, I thought both IE11 and Chrome would work from the same Function, but in Chrome, it starts at line 500, and in IE, it starts at line 100 one.

I would like to be able to start from the same elementName's Function even if the browsers are different.

I don't know why it starts from a different place in different browsers, so what should I do to make it start from the same Function with the same elementName?
By the way, if possible, I would like IE to start from the 500th line as well as Chrome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [FYI](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/)

Comment: IE is retired, so I suggest you focus more on modern browsers instead of IE.  In addition, they are based on different engines and the components for parsing the script will vary, so I think this should be by design.